# Doom 4 (Doom 2016) Multiplayer: What's the difference between red and yellow hit numbers?

Tags: doom-2016

When I hit an enemy player, a number pops up showing how much damage I've done to the player. But sometimes the number is red and sometimes it's yellow. What's the red for and what's the yellow for?

Comment: I think the yellow numbers are normal bullets and the red numbers are fire damage projectiles.

Comment: Yellow numbers are always higher than the red ones (if shooting at the same part of the body). So my guess is that the yellow numbers are showing critical hits and the red numbers normal hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Red - Normal hits.

Yellow - Critical hits, like headshots with Vortex rifle, or well-placed close-range shot with a shotgun.

Answer (score 0):

The yellow indicator shows normal hits to any bodypart except the head and the red indicators are for headshots , so normaly the red indicator shows a higher number due to the fact that headshots deal more damage.